# Using pattern matching to sort from a file, Java

Tags: java, regex, sorting, pattern-matching, filereader

So I've gotten my program to the point where it properly separates the lines of the text file properly and can even match the pattern for the first line of text but i also need to be able to detect and separate the address lines of the text file and sort them based on their direction or street/broadway but i cant even get the initial pattern to be detected for the address setup. Am i using regex wrong and is that why the address portion wont be detected properly?

**CODE**

```
package csi311;

// Import some standard Java libraries.
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * Hello world example.  Shows passing in command line arguments, in this case a filename. 
 * If the filename is given, read in the file and echo it to stdout.
 */
public class HelloCsi311 {

    /**
     * Class construtor.
     */
    public HelloCsi311() {
    }


    /**
     * @param filename the name of a file to read in 
     * @throws Exception on anything bad happening 
     */
    public void run(String filename) throws Exception {
        if (filename != null) {
            readFile(filename); 
        }
    }


    /**
     * @param filename the name of a file to read in 
     * @throws Exception on anything bad happening 
     */
    private void readFile(String filename) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Dumping file " + filename); 
        // Open the file and connect it to a buffered reader.
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));  
        ArrayList<String> foundaddr = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = null;  
        String pattern = "^\\d\\d\\d-[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]-\\d\\d\\d\\d";
        String address[] = new String[4];
        address[0] = "\\d{1,3}\\s\\[A-Za-z]{1,20}";
        address[1] = "\\d{1,3}\\s\\[A-Za-z]{1,20}\\s\\d{1,3}\\[A-Za-z]{1,20}\\s\\[A-Za-z]{1,20}";
        address[2] = "\\d{1,3}\\s\\d{1,3}\\[A-Za-z]{1,20}\\s\\[A-Za-z]{1,20}";
        address[3] = "\\d\\d\\s\\[A-Za-z]{1,20}";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        // Get lines from the file one at a time until there are no more.
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            String sample = line.replaceAll("\\s+,", ",").replaceAll(",+\\s",",");
            String[] result = sample.split(",");
            String pkgId = result[0].trim().toUpperCase();
            String pkgAddr = result[1].trim();


            Float f = Float.valueOf(result[2]);
            for(String str : result){
                // Trying to match for different types
                for(String pat : address){
                    if(str.matches(pat)){
                        System.out.println(pat);
                    }
                }



                if(f < 50 && !pkgId.matches(pattern)) {
                    Matcher m = r.matcher(str);
                    if(m.find()) {
                        foundaddr.add(str);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(foundaddr != null) {
            System.out.println(foundaddr.size());
        }   

        // Close the buffer and the underlying file.
        br.close();
    }



    /**
     * @param args filename
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Make an instance of the class.
        HelloCsi311 theApp = new HelloCsi311();
        String filename = null; 
        // If a command line argument was given, use it as the filename.
        if (args.length > 0) {
            filename = args[0]; 
        }
        try { 
            // Run the run(), passing in the filename, null if not specified.
            theApp.run(filename);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // If anything bad happens, report it.
            System.out.println("Something bad happened!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }
}
```

**Text File**

```
123-ABC-4567, 15 W. 15th St., 50.1
456-BGT-9876,22 Broadway,24
QAZ-456-QWER, 100 East 20th Street,50
Q2Z-457-QWER, 200 East 20th Street, 49
6785-FGH-9845 ,45 5th Ave, 12.2,
678-FGH-9846 ,45 5th Ave, 12.2

123-ABC-9999, 46 Foo Bar, 220.0
347-poy-3465, 101 B'way,24
```

Below is the lines of code that should be able to process the address lines but for some reason it wont match the pattern and the outputs which properly separate the address lines and can be seen in the print statement above the for loop dealing with the addresses but for some reason the address lines arent even being detected as matches and im confused as to why that is.

**Line of Code Issue is with**

```
  for(String str : result){
      //System.out.println(str);
      // Trying to match for different types
      for(String pat : address){
          if(str.matches(pat)){
              System.out.println(pat);
          }
      }
```

**Desired Output** - Edit as Requested -

```
22 Broadway
45 5th Ave
101 B'way
```

Comment: Why not just split on commas or use a proper CSV parser? You probably don't need a regex here.

Comment: The lines are split on commas and are printed separately just fine but i then need to be able to match the pattern of the split lines and then separate them into their specific sections which i can do in arraylist but the issue is that for some reason the patterns for the address portions arent being detected and im confused on why that is for everything i've read up about regex and formatting suggest that my formatting for it is correct. That and it worked just fine for detecting the matched pattern for the first part of the text in the file. That and use of regex is required.

Comment: Example, `456-BGT-9876
22 Broadway
24
678-FGH-9846
45 5th Ave
12.2
347-poy-3465
101 B'way
24` 
is what is printed out and i need to be able to pattern match the `22 Broadway` portions. Using a regex i even made it to specificly target that example but for some reason even then its not being detected as a match. I need to be able to detect this match because then i will need to adjust it to be able to detect the `Broadway` portion and then add that to an arraylist as a delivery needed to go to a `Broadway`

Comment: Can you add your desired output to the question? I don't fully understand what you're looking for.

Comment: Done, Thats the output im attempting to get, from the text file its anything after the first comma, thats the address portion of the delivery and i need to pattern match to those addresses and be able to print them out. Once i can get it to the point that the addresses are matched ill then worry about matching to the specific patterns of `broadway` or `Ave` or `B'way` which in this case `Broadway and B'way` are both considered broadways and would be lumped into array list grouping.

Comment: I should have mentioned it earlier, but you should take a look at how to write a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Most people don't want to read a wall of irrelevant code, so keeping your example minimal, verifiable, and complete will help you get answers faster.

Comment: Ah yeah my bad there, i realized it was a lot to post but given the question i thought that the majority of the code would be wanted to understand whats going on but i probably could have cut out the main method entirely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with your Regex. `\\d\\d\\s\\[A-Za-z]{1,20}` for example, after all of the escaping becomes `\d\d\s\[A-Za-z]{1,20}`. This breaks down as follows:

- `\d`: Match any digit
- `\d`: Match any digit
- `\s`: Match any whitespace character
- `\[`: Match the `[` character
- `A-Za-z`: Match the literal text `A-Za-z`
- `]`: Match the literal character `]`

  - `{1,20}`: Match the preceding character (`]`) 1-20 times.

The regex you probably want is `\d\d\s[A-Za-z]{1,20}` which, as an escaped string is `\\d\\d\\s[A-Za-z]{1,20}`. Notice that there's no `\` before the `[`.

Something else to keep in mind is that regular expressions can match anywhere in the string. For example the regex `a` would match the string `a` but would also match `abc`, `bac`, `abracadabra`, etc. To avoid this, you must use the anchoring symbols `^` and `$` to match the start and end respectively. Your regex then becomes `^\\d\\d\\s[A-Za-z]{1,20}$`.

I also noticed that you're matching each column against the regex using with the for loop `for(String str : result){`. It seems to me that you should only be matching against `result[1]` or `pkgAddr`.

A final note, take a look at [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/). It will allow you to test your regular expressions against a bunch of inputs to see if they match.

Comment: thank you very much! Fixed up my regex issue and i have a better understanding of how it works, got a few hiccups still in my program but nothing that i shouldnt be able to solve.